# Как разделить строку на две и вывести их как два разных блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, reactjs

**Имеется React компонент -**

```
    function Product (props) {
    
        const {
            prod_id: id,
            prod_name : title,
            prod_status: status,
            prod_price: price,
            prod_oldprice : oldPrice,
        } = props;
    
    
        let oldPriceChecker = (oldPriceValue) => {
            if (oldPriceValue) {
                let oldPriceStr = oldPriceValue + ' zł';
                return(oldPriceStr);
            }else {
                return('');
            }
        }
    
    
        return (
        
        <div className="row">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-image">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
                <span className="card-title">{title}</span>
                <hr className="card_hr" />
                <p className="card_price" >{price} zł</p>
                <div className="card_price old_price">{oldPriceChecker(oldPrice)}</div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
        ) 
    }

export {Product}
```

**Данные в const приходят из этого файла [JSON](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Sky-shop-Task-React-/blob/main/public/products.json)**

**Вопрос : Переменная prod_status: status может содержать несколько значений (например "new,promotion", если это так, нужно разделить это на два слова и создать для каждого отдельный блок, так как сейчас  блок приходит вся строка**

**Сейчас сайт выглядит так (new,saleout) в одном блоке**

[image: Сайт]

**Нужно так (new,saleout и прочее в отдельных блоках)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
let string = "item1,item2"
let array = string.split(",")

console.log(array); // ['item1', 'item2']
```

а дальше через цикл обрабатывайте как обычный массив

Comment: let string = status
    let array = string.split(",")

    console.log(array);

Вывел то, что нужно но в придачу выдал ошибок

Product.jsx:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

The above error occurred in the <Product> component:

Comment: @Yevhenii А вы где напсиали это?

Comment: Это пример, это не часть вашего кода, исходя из моего примера, вам надо самостоятельно написать логику в компоненте